# Button click function Connect with postgresql

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am new to Django and Python. I Create a Website with a Table. I Want to add a new column to my existing Table with a Button click on the html website. Is anyone there who can Show me how to Solve this problem? Thanks
in this link i uploaded all files from my project. i write it in pycharm, python, django .

Comment: Please see [ask]

Comment: add a column to the table in HTML is not related to django or python. make your question as HTML, CSS, and jquery tag. also if you have any problems, share some codes here!

Answer (score 0):

```
'''    Timeline.html:
        {% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
        {% block blogContent %}
        
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <form action="{% url 'blog:create_post' %}" method="post">
                {{ post_form }}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit">Add message</button>
            </form>
             {% endif %}
        
        
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <form action="{% url 'blog:create_column' %}" method="post">
                {{ column_form }}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit">Add column</button>
            </form>
        
            {% endif %}
        
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <form action="{% url 'blog:new_column' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ newcolumn_form }}
                    <button type="submit">New column</button>
                </form>
            {% endif %}
        
        
        
            <style>
            table, th, td {
              border: 1px solid black;
              border-collapse: collapse; }
            </style>
        
        
        
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                    <th>Erstellt am</th>
                    <th>User_ID</th>
                    <th>Spalte</th>
        
                </tr>
                {% for post in posts %}
                <tr>
                    <td> {{ post.id }} </td>
                    <td> {{ post.message }} </td>
                    <td> {{ post.created_at }} </td>
                    <td> {{ post.user_id}} </td>
                    <td> {{ post.created_attt}} </td>
        
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        
        {% for post in posts %}
            {% empty %}
                {% if user == request.user %}
                <p> Du hast noch keinen Eintrag verfasst</p>
                {% else %}
                <p> {{ user.username }} hat noch keinen Eintrag verfasst</p>
                {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        
        {% endblock %}
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'''    '''URLS.py
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    
    app_name = 'blog'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('<str:username>/timeline/', views.timeline_view, name='timeline'),
        path('create-post/', views.post_view, name='create_post'),
        path('create-column/', views.column_view, name='create_column'),
        path('new-column/', views.newcolumn_view, name='new_column'),
    ]
    
    models.py:
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone
    
    
    class BlogPost (models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        message = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        created_attt = models.CharField(max_length=222, default='')
    
    
    views.py:
    import logging
    
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
    from .forms import PostForm, CreateForm, NewColumnForm
    from .models import BlogPost
    
    def index(request):
        return render(request, 'blog/base.html')
    
    def timeline_view(request, username):
        post_form = PostForm()
        column_form = CreateForm()
        newcolumn_form = NewColumnForm()
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-created_at')
        return render(request, 'blog/timeline.html', {'posts': posts, 'post_form': post_form, 'column_form': column_form, 'user': user, 'newcolumn_form': newcolumn_form})
    
    @login_required
    @require_POST
    def post_view(request):
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST)
        logging.debug(post_form)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            post = post_form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:timeline', kwargs={'username': request.user.username}))
    
    @login_required
    @require_POST
    def column_view(request):
        column_form = CreateForm(request.POST)
        if column_form.is_valid():
            createcolumn = column_form.save(commit=False)
            createcolumn.user = request.user
            createcolumn.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:timeline', kwargs={'username': request.user.username}))
    
    @login_required
    @require_POST
    def newcolumn_view(request):
        newcolumn_form = CreateForm(request.POST)
        if newcolumn_form.is_valid():
            newcolumn = newcolumn_form.save(commit=False)
            newcolumn.user = request.user
            newcolumn.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:timeline', kwargs={'username': request.user.username}))
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
''' forms.py :
    from django import forms
    
    from .models import BlogPost
    
    
    class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = BlogPost
            fields = ['message', ]
            labels = {
                'message': 'Nachricht',
    
            }
    
    
    class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = BlogPost
            fields = ['created_attt', ]
            labels = {
                'created_attt': 'Spalte',
            }
    
    
    class NewColumnForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = BlogPost
            exclude = []
            fields = ['created_attt', ]
            labels = {
                'created_attt': 'Neue Spalte',
            }
    
    
'''
```